# Where can I get php-mcrypt for PHP 7?

Tags: php, mcrypt, centos7

I've upgraded PHP to PHP 7 and am now seeing the following error `Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_MODE_ECB`. I am running CentOS 7  and having trouble updating php-mcrypt.

I found it on Arch Linux but am unfamiliar with Pacman and am having trouble setting it up.

**Edit**: This is where I am now. I've tried removing the installed packages to install the required but am having no such luck.

```
$ sudo yum install php*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Cannot open: php-7.0.2-1.mga6.src.rpm. Skipping.
Examining php70-php-mcrypt-7.0.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm: php70-php-mcrypt-7.0.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64
Marking php70-php-mcrypt-7.0.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining php70-php-mcrypt-7.0.0-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm: php70-php-mcrypt-7.0.0-2.el6.remi.x86_64
Marking php70-php-mcrypt-7.0.0-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirror.cs.pitt.edu
* epel: mirror.symnds.com
* extras: ftp.linux.ncsu.edu
* remi: mirrors.mediatemple.net
* remi-php56: mirrors.mediatemple.net
* remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
* updates: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
No package php-mcrypt-7.0.2-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz available.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php70-php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:7.0.0-1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php70-php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.0-1.el7.remi for package: php70-php-mcrypt-7.0.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php70-php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:7.0.0-2.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php70-php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.0-2.el6.remi for package: php70-php-mcrypt-7.0.0-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php70-php-mcrypt-7.0.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (/php70-php-mcrypt-7.0.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64)
Requires: php70-php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.0-1.el7.remi
Installed: php70-php-common-7.0.2-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
php70-php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.2-1.el7.remi
Available: php70-php-common-7.0.1-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
php70-php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.1-1.el7.remi
Error: Package: php70-php-mcrypt-7.0.0-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (/php70-php-mcrypt-7.0.0-2.el6.remi.x86_64)
Requires: php70-php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.0-2.el6.remi
Installed: php70-php-common-7.0.2-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
php70-php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.2-1.el7.remi
Available: php70-php-common-7.0.1-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
php70-php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.1-1.el7.remi
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: You should have both a good reason and a good understanding of encryption to use ECB mode, it is generally not a recommend/secure mode. [ECB vs CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29) mode (scroll down to the penguin).

Comment: This is occurring in the core files of Magento.

Comment: About mcrypt, please read http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/07/07/About-libmcrypt-and-php-mcrypt

Comment: Seriously, don't use ECB mode. Also, shame on Magento.

Comment: @scott where can I learn more about why you suggested this? I can extend the class and rewrite it if called for.

Comment: http://filippo.io/the-ecb-penguin/

Comment: I also wrote a [guide to choosing a PHP cryptography library](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/11/choosing-right-cryptography-library-for-your-php-project-guide) last year...

Comment: At the risk of coming across as snooty, push back on your vendor about using mcrypt.  "mcrypt" and "ECB" are VERY bad ideas.  http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/07/07/About-libmcrypt-and-php-mcrypt  Remi is a maintainer and voting member on PHP-CORE, he knows a thing or two about a thing or two.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sudo yum install php*
```

This is terribly wrong, there are hundred of php packages, obviously not what you want.

You should use a single PHP repository, and only install the needed packages (extensions / libraries)

For "remi" repository, see the Wizard: http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

As you have php70-php-common-7.0.2-1.el7.remi.x86_64, you have to use exactly the same version, so php70-php-mcrypt-7.0.2-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (which is in "remi-safe" repository).

Comment: Thank you.  The link you provided did the trick. I did have to uninstall a conflict first though.

Comment: Thanks alot, i was facing a problem with php56w and package.
and when i follow your steps, the problem is solved, you safe my day :D

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have fixed issue,please find the extension link for the same.

```
# rmp -qa | grep php 
php70w-intl
php70w-soap

# yum install php70w-mcrypt
```

Link for PHP extension : https://webtatic.com/packages/php70/